# A pop-up window opens as soon as you move the page

Tags: javascript, php, css

Let me explain first.

- `Page A` is the main page.
- `Page B` has a `pop-up button` and the `pop-up window` will not open until you press the `pop-up button`.

When you click on a particular `A tag` on `page A`, go to `Page B`.
Can I automatically open a `pop-up window` without pressing the `pop-up button`?

Comment: you can, with Javascript. Don't know how though

Comment: If it is javascript, use `load` event, This event will fire when your page/document is loaded. [Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)

Comment: _“Can I automatically open a pop-up window without pressing the pop-up button?”_ - in most browsers these days, the popup blocker will probably prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onload event of js for this. please refer [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

Sample from html triggered function:-

```js
function myFunction(from) {
  alert("function triggered by :"+from);
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction('load')">
   <button onclick="myFunction('click')">Try it</button>
</body>
```

Comment: You've been very helpful. Thank you.